# Joining multiple queries on a table and get a single select result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table with columns Costcenter, Vendor, Tool , cost and quarter. I want to get result of cost difference between two quarters (say 15/16 Q3 and 15/16 Q2) as:

[image]

I have created query to get result for Costcenter and Vendor only initially  as  below but it is not joining two appropriately:
[image]

```
select a.Costcenter,c.Vendor,(SumA-SumB) as costcenter_diff, (SumC-SumD) as vendor_diff from
    (select Costcenter ,sum(CostTotal) as SumA
                  from Rawdata
                  where Quarter='15/16 Q3'
                  group by Costcenter)as a,
                  (select Costcenter,sum(CostTotal) as SumB
                  from Rawdata
                  where Quarter='15/16 Q2'
                  group by Costcenter) as b
     Join 
    (select Costcenter,Vendor,sum(CostTotal) as SumC
                  from Rawdata
                  where Quarter='15/16 Q3'
                  group by Costcenter,Vendor)as c,
                  (select Costcenter,Vendor,sum(CostTotal) as SumD
                  from Rawdata
                  where Quarter='15/16 Q2' 
                  group by Costcenter,Vendor) as d where a.Costcenter = b.Costcenter and  
                  c.Costcenter= d.Costcenter and c.Vendor= d.Vendor;
```

Comment: Kindly provide your question little more clear. What is  I want to get result of cost difference between two quarters (say 15/16 Q3 and 15/16 Q2). Q3? Q2?

Comment: Also, place your query in your question as text, not as an image.

Comment: Q3 is quarter 3 and Q2 is Quarter 2 of year 2015-16. I want the difference of cost between these quarters on Costcenter  and Vendor wise. I am selecting cost  of two quarters  as SumA for '15/16 Q3' and SumB  for '15/16 Q2' and subtracting them in first SELECT as  (SumA-SumB)   for costcenter and similarly for vendor also. but i am not able to  get the output in a form as mentioned in snapshot at the top.

Comment: Where is the column that specifies 15/16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use conditional aggregation.  For instance:

```
select CostCenter,
       sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q2' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq2,
       sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q3' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq3
from rawdata rd
where quarter in ('15/16 Q3', '15/16 Q2');
```

Then, do this for vendors and join them together:

```
select ccv.costcenter, ccv.vendor,
       (cc.sumq3 - cc.sumq2) as cc_diff,
       (ccv.sumq3 - ccv.sumq2) as ccv_diff
from (select CostCenter,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q2' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq2,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q3' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq3
      from rawdata rd
      where quarter in ('15/16 Q3', '15/16 Q2')
      group by CostCenter
     ) cc join
     (select CostCenter, vendor,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q2' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq2,
             sum(case when quarter = '15/16 Q3' then costtotal else 0 end) as sumq3
      from rawdata rd
      where quarter in ('15/16 Q3', '15/16 Q2')
      group by CostCenter, vendor
     ) ccv
     on cc.costcenter = ccv.costcenter;
```

Notes:

- Name columns something reasonable.  `a` and `b` just don't make it easy to understand a query.
- `JOIN` conditions should be in an `ON` clause not a `WHERE` clause.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and suggestion. It worked perfectly. If possible can you please also provide me solution how to filter cc_diff for values > 1000 in same query ?

Comment: @user6559913 . . . You can use a `where` clause, but you need to use the expression rather than the column alias.

Comment: I am able to get it using "having" clause . I am using it for selecting percentage changes > 30 on costcenter_change, vendor_change and Tool_change as :

Comment: I am able to get it using "having" clause . I am using it for selecting percentage changes > 30 on costcenter_change, vendor_change and Tool_change. but now i want to get the maximum of Tool_diff  for a vendor . I tried doing using "having" but i does not work ,I also tried doing "max" at top SELECT on Tool_diff, in this case i am able to get max for Tool_diff but the Tool for which this max should be is not coming. It is taking some other tool from that Vendor only. If possible can you please help me?

Comment: @user6559913 . . . Yes, MySQL also extends the use of the `having` clause so you can filter on a column alias as well.  That extension is convenient in this situation.

Comment: I am badly stuck. ..Can you please help me with finding max group wise as mentioned in my last comment ?

Comment: @user6559913 . . . New questions should be asked as a question and not in a comment.